Colab disconnecting when extracting dataset
# Get TensorFlow Datasets
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
datasets_list = tfds.list_builders() # get all available datasets in TFDS
print("food101" in datasets_list) # is the dataset we're after available?

(train_data, test_data), ds_info = tfds.load(name="food101", # target dataset to get from TFDS
                                             split=["train", "validation"], # what splits of data should we get? note: not all datasets have train, valid, test
                                             shuffle_files=True, # shuffle files on download?
                                             as_supervised=True, # download data in tuple format (sample, label), e.g. (image, label)
                                             with_info=True) # include dataset metadata? if so, tfds.load() returns tuple (data, ds_info)

Source here

Colab is keeping disconnecting when it comes to extract the download dataset
Changed Wi-Fi
Changed processor

All didn't work
I want to find a way to keep the extraction, or a way to use the dataset another than using tensorflow datasets, the screenshot below shows the commands I wrote.


can you add the minimum code and steps so people can reproduce (including imports)? 2) Is this Colab Enterprise or colab.google.com ?


I was able to reproduce your issue in colab.google.com. Will try Colab Enterprise and get back to you on Colab

was not able to reproduce with Colab anymore, do you still see this issue?
